# Excel file gets corrupted after launching an executable jar

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Eclipse project with the following code that uses Apache POI.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        XSSFWorkbook sourceWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook("input.xlsx");
        XSSFSheet sheet = sourceWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        // do stuff
        sourceWorkbook.close();         
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I launch it from Eclipse, it works properly. Since I created the executable jar, when I use it, the Excel input file passes from 9 to 1 kB and it won't open anymore.

[EDIT: since I was asked:

- the file is only read, I never write it.
- the version of apache POI is 3.15
  ]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does `// do stuff` really do? Does it include a `sourceWorkbook.write()` operation? Do you just read from the workbook/worksheet or do you change it and store the changes?

Comment: It may be important to know if the execution raises an exception (that is not thrown when running locally in Eclipse) and what is its stack trace. Also, you must be opening a stream (to read the excel file) but I don't see you closing it in a finally block.

Comment: @deHaar it does never write, it only reads the content of teh excel.

Comment: I would use a `try` with resources and open the workbook using a `FileInputStream`. That way you can make sure resources get closed properly…

Comment: @deHaar, it was my first attempt, and I'm not even sure about the version of Java on the pc where it will run. I had the same problem when XSSFWorkbook sourceWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook("input.xlsx"); was in try with resources.

Comment: Which version of apache poi are you using? I meant something slightly differen from opening the workbook in a try-with-resources statement… I'll provide my idea in an answer soon.

Comment: @deHaar the version of apache poi I0m using is 3.15.

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse
Put your file in the distro jar and load with `XSSFWorkbook sourceWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/input.xlsx"));` (Better inside try-with-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following option:

- create a `FileInputStream` to the workbook path
- do that in a `try`-with-resources statement
- close the workbook inside the `try` block

Maybe like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String wbPath = "input.xlsx";
    // use an auto-closable resource stream 
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(wbPath)) {
        // then use that in order to open the workbook
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        // then open the sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        
        // and do stuff…
        
        // Having done stuff, close the workbook explicitly
        workbook.close();
        // and let the try with resources close the input stream
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // do proper exception handling here
        throw new RuntimeException("file " + wbPath + " seems not to exist");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do proper exception handling here, too
        throw new RuntimeException("error during read or write operation");
    }
}
```

The `RuntimeException`s are just for making the code work and not just printing a stack trace there. As the comments say, you might want to do something better in the `catch` blocks.

As an alternative to `new XSSFWorkbook(fis)` you could use the [`WorkbookFactory`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) in order to `create(fis)`.